# Single Sign on implementation for my sites in same domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, single-sign-on, azure-redis-cache

We have a application running already lets say **a.example.com**, now we are planning to add one more application as **b.example.com**. We are already storing user session of a.example.com in Azure Redis cache.  Is there a simple way to provide SSO between my two sites, by utilizing the existing Redis session store.

Note : please dont suggest using identity framework, as I dont want to have a separate server, to do authentication. Correct me If I was wrong here guys.

Thanks in Advance
Ganesan S

Answer (score 0):

I will first say what could be a solution, then give what my work has done since we have multiple sights that all deal with their own sessions, but are all linked.

When you create a session for a.example.com, could you also create b.example.com as well and have both put in the Redis store? Then when a person signs out you can find the session for both sites based on the user and delete both at once.

Another option could be to have 1 session that both sites look for. That way each user only has 1 session, so there is only 1 to create and 1 to destroy. You could set up the domain to be by example.com unless there are other sites that should not see that domain.

We use a Service Provider that creates a sign in hub that all of our sites point to. Then each site gets its own session that has a domain over everything. Then when someone logs out the server will delete all sessions at once and call logout for the user at the service provider. In your case you could treat the Redis session store as a sort of Service provider storing the sessions for the users that your websites look at for user validation?